# check dropdown value contain specific text using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

In a set of dropdown menus, if selected value contain text `Misc`, I would run specific code. I am using below code to check the value of dropdown, but not working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("[id^='select_debit']").on('change', function() {


             if ( this.value ~= 'Misc')

                {

                    run code A

                } else {

                    run code B
                }
        });
});
```

Any suggestions to achieve this ?

EDIT:

To be more specific, dropdown does not have specific value called Misc, but with some additional text
ex: Travel Misc, Web Misc.

So I am looking for any options which has word "Misc" in it

Comment: Simply it should be `$(this).val()` not this.value.

Comment: Also it's `!=` for not equal. So it's `if ($(this).val() != 'Misc')`

Comment: `$('option:selected' , this).text().indexOf('Misc') > -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
var n = (this.value).includes("Misc");
```

To check if string contains in given string

You can get more details about includes from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("[id^='select_debit']").on('change', function() {


    if (this.value.includes('Misc'))

    {

      console.log('A');

    } else {

      console.log('B')
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_debit">
  <option>Select option</option>
  <option value="Travel Misc">Travel Misc</option>
  <option value="Web Misc">Web Misc</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>

</select>
```

Comment: In the context of the code. `this` would have a different meaning.

Comment: Its working, May I know problem, because I am not getting

Answer (score 1):

- If you mean by value -> selected option text so you can use `$('option:selected' , this)`
- If you mean by value -> the value of the selected option use `this.value`
- In both cases you need to use `indexOf()` to check if the string is in the value or not

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("[id^='select_debit']").on('change', function() {
    if ($('option:selected' , this).text().indexOf('Misc') > -1){
      console.log('Misc is Found');
    } else {
      console.log('Not Found');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_debit_12">
  <option value="1">No</option>
  <option value="2">Here Misc</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $("[id^='select_debit']").on('change', function() 
   {
      if ($(this).val() == 'Misc')
      {
         run code A
      } else {
         run code B
        }
   });
});
```